# Initializing static field

Tags: c++, arduino

I don't understand why the following code cannot be compiled:

```
// program.h
class Sensor;

class Program {
private:
    static Sensor* sensor;
public:
    void SetSensor(Sensor *s) { sensor = s; }
};
```

I get this compiler error:
**cc3No0Or.ltrans0.ltrans.o*: In function Program::SetSensor(Sensor*)
program.h:##: undefined reference to Program  sensor**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have a declaration for the static member, you need also the definition...
Add

```
Sensor* Sensor::sensor;
```

in a .cpp file and it will work.